# How do I force an iOS app to hang but not crash?

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, freeze

I need to test something with my app where it hangs but it hard to reproduce the hang. Is there an easy way to create a sample iOS app that hangs or freezes but doesn't crash to the home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try blocking the main queue:

**Swift**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10) // Hangs for 10 seconds.
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10]; // Hangs for 10 seconds.
});
```

You can “safely” call this hack from elsewhere in you app.

Comment: Thanks! I added an Obj-C version too.

Comment: Hey @SteveMoser, if this worked as expected please don’t forget to mark it as the accepted answer ;) Thanks man!